# how do i filter a data in quickmongoi so that it would show only names of users who are in the guild only in the leaderboard command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, quick.db

js and quickmongo for a leaderboard command but it shows the named of all the users in the database and I want it to show names of users who are in the guild only. Any help is highly appreciated . I tried filtering it too...
My current code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, db) => {
    let eco = await db.fetch(`eco_${message.author.id}`)
    if(eco !== 'START') return message.reply(`you/They have not yet started your economy journey.\n**Start it now by typing \`gg ecostart\`**`)
    const ic = '<:mythicalcoin:842637611150606356>'
    let data = await db.startsWith("mon_");
    message.guild.members.fetch().then((m) => {
      m.forEach(user => {
          data.filter(i => i.ID.endsWith(user.id))
          })
}).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
        })
    
    let money = data.sort((a, b) => (b.data-a.data))
    
                      
    

   
    money.length = 20;
    var finalLb = ""; 
    for (var i in money) {
      finalLb += `${money.indexOf(money[i])+1}.${(await message.guild.members.fetch(money[i].ID.split('_')[1])).username ? (await message.guild.members.fetch(money[i].ID.split('_')[1])).username : "Unknown User#0000"} || '\n' : ${ic} \`${parseInt(JSON.stringify(money[i].data)).toLocaleString()}\`\n`;
   }
    
        
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(`Leaderboard`, message.guild.iconURL())
    .setColor("PURPLE")
    .setDescription(finalLb)
    .setFooter(bot.user.tag, bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
    .setTimestamp()
    message.channel.send(embed);
    }
module.exports.help = {
  name:"rich",
  aliases: ["lb", "leaderboard"]
}
```

Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) doesn't modify arrays in place, it only returns the filtered result. For example:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const filteredArr = arr.filter((num) => num !== 2);

// this still shows all the numbers,
// because arr.filter() didn't modify the
// original array
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3];

// however, it did *return* a filtered
// array
console.log(filteredArr); // [1, 3];
```

So, you'll simply need to reassign `data` to the filtered array.

```js
let data = await db.startsWith('mon_');
message.guild.members
 .fetch()
 .then((m) => {
  m.forEach((user) => {
   data = data.filter((i) => i.ID.endsWith(user.id));
  });
 })
 .catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
 });
```

However, this still won't work. This is because you're filtering the array within a callback. The whole purpose of a callback is to trigger *after* a promise is resolved, so by the time you're able to filter the array, all of the other code will have already been executed.

Understanding promises:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises
- https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html
- https://javascript.info/async-await

If you choose to use `async/await`, you can refactor your code like so:

```js
let data = await db.startsWith('mon_');
try {
 const m = await message.guild.members.fetch();
 m.forEach((user) => {
  data = data.filter((i) => i.ID.endsWith(user.id));
 });
} catch (e) {
 console.log(e);
}
```

While working, this solution is not optimal, since you have to filter and reassign `data` for every single member. Instead, you should try to only do it once. You can achieve this using [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const m = await message.guild.members.fetch();
data = data.filter((i) => m.some((user) => i.ID.endsWith(user.id)));
```